# Sort questions by number of views

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

The available options to sort the questions on academia.stackexchange.com are *newest*, *featured*, *frequent*, *votes*, *active*, and *unanswered*. While the option *votes* does reflect quite well what are the important or good questions, there are also several questions which have received a relatively high number of views but still not so many up-votes. Would it be possible have an option of sorting the questions according to number of *views*?

Or maybe this is not just specific to Academia, but SE in general? I am not very familiar with the other sites.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113042/can-we-have-a-sort-by-view-count